# Plot line graph with each row of dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to plot a line showing the ranking of each of these roller coasters as a function of the year that they were ranked. For example for the second row (Boulder Dash, I would like a line graph showing the value 1 for 2013-2016, and then 3 and 4 for 2017 and 2018, respectively.

Since the years will be constant for each different coaster, I tried setting the x-axis with:
x = range(6)
then I would like to plot:
plot(x, ranking) for each different roller coaster. What I am confused about is how to get those y values (rating) in a format that could be plotted.
[Roller Coaster DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWgJO.jpg)

Comment: Please see [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the dataframe from the image, I would use `seaborn` line plot that already implements a `hue` parameter,  but first, reset the `Name` index and `melt` the dataframe:

```
import seaborn as sns

df_melted = df.reset_index().melt(id_vars=['Name'])
sns.lineplot(data = df_melted, x='Year of Rank', y ='value', hue='Name')
```